# I cannot sort the Linked List Alphabetically in C

Tags: c

I am new to programming and StackOverflow. I cannot understand the other questions answers because i cannot read the code that good. So, can anyone help me with my code? I am trying to sort the given strings in the linked list in alpabetical order. They soon will be taken from the user. But i am trying to debug before coding that phase.

It doesnt give an output when i try to print the linked list as sorted.
There is no syntax error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct node
{
    char word[100];
    struct node *next;
}node;

node* addToLinkedList(node *head, char word[])
{
    node *temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    strcpy(temp->word, word);

    if(head==NULL)
    {
        temp->next=NULL;
        head=temp;
        return head;
    }

    node *iter = head;
    while(iter->next!=NULL)
        iter=iter->next;

    iter->next=temp;
    temp->next=NULL;
    return head;
}

int listLenght(node *head)
{
    int len=0;
    node *iter = head;
    while(iter!=NULL)
    {
        len++;
        iter=iter->next;
    }

    return len;
}

void sortList(node *head)
{
    int len = listLenght(head);

    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        node *tmp1 = head;
        node *tmp2 = tmp1->next;
        for(j=0; j<len; j++)
        {
            int idx = 0;
            while(tmp1->word[idx] == tmp2->word[idx])
                idx++;

            if(tmp1->word[idx] > tmp2->word[idx])
            {
                char wrd[100];
                strcpy(wrd, tmp1->word);
                strcpy(tmp1->word, tmp2->word);
                strcpy(tmp2->word, wrd);

            }
            tmp1=tmp1->next;
            tmp2 = tmp2->next;
        }
        tmp1 = head;
    }
}

void printfLinkedList(node *head)
{
    node *iter = head;
    while(iter!=NULL)
    {
         printf("%s ->", iter->word);
         iter=iter->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    node *list = NULL;
    list=addToLinkedList(list,"one" );
    list=addToLinkedList(list,"two" );
    list=addToLinkedList(list, "three");
    list=addToLinkedList(list,"four" );
    list=addToLinkedList(list,"five" );
    sortList(list);
    printfLinkedList(list);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorting function doesnt work. I tried to use bubble sort but a problem occurs i cannot understand why it does

Comment: What do you mean by "a problem occurs"? Does it crash? Give you the wrong output? Something else?

Comment: "a problem occurs" is not a problem description. What problem? Explain the desired vs actual behaviours in full, and/or quote any errors received in full, in your post.

Comment: There is no syntax error but it doesnt give an output at all when i try to print it as sorted.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add all information there instead of writing comments. Comments are to ask for information or to suggest improvements.

Comment: Okay thanks for letting me know. I am editing the question now

Comment: `while(tmp1->word[idx] == tmp2->word[idx]) idx++;` - this can overflow the buffer. You need to check idx < 100 too. But you should just use strcmp instead.

Comment: Minor FYI: the word 'Lenght' is spelled 'Length'.

Comment: This question shows effort and although it did not originally provide a perfectly detailed problem description such as what _might_ be provided by an experience SO user, OP has since edited, but the down votes remain.  Why I wonder?.

Comment: @ryyker Not me, but the question is still "debug my code for me" which isn't a great SO question.

Comment: If you're still having problems then I'd guess you're advancing tmp2 past the end of the list. Perhaps j should start at 1 not 0? Or maybe better still replace the j loop with, `while (tmp2 != NULL)`

Comment: @Rup I have been trying to debug to code at least 4 hours straight. I deleted and rewrote the code 3 times. Sent to question to my classmates to help me and they couldnt able to solve it. I wouldnt be posting this if i didnt put the effort in it.

Comment: OK, but if Bodo is right and this is a segmentation fault (and it looks convincing to me) then you should have seen a runtime error straight away, especially if you're running it under a debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program is terminated with a segmentation fault at this line

```
            while(tmp1->word[idx] == tmp2->word[idx])
```

because `tmp2` is `NULL` and you try to dereference the pointer.

Since `len` is the number of elements in the list, in the last loop cycle here

```
        node *tmp1 = head;
        node *tmp2 = tmp1->next;
        for(j=0; j<len; j++)
        {
            /* ... */
            tmp1=tmp1->next;
            tmp2 = tmp2->next;
        }
```

`tmp1` will point to the last list element and `tmp2` will point to its non-existent successor, i.e. `NULL`.

To see this error you should run your program in a debugger and/or use a memory access checker like `valgrind`.

You can change this loop to one cycle less to make your program work as shown below. (I, additionally, modified your code to show the list before and after sorting.)

```
/* ... */
{
    int len = listLenght(head);

    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        node *tmp1 = head;
        node *tmp2 = tmp1->next;
        for(j=0; j<len-1; j++)
        {
            int idx = 0;
            while(tmp1->word[idx] == tmp2->word[idx])
                idx++;

            if(tmp1->word[idx] > tmp2->word[idx])
            {
                char wrd[100];
                strcpy(wrd, tmp1->word);
                strcpy(tmp1->word, tmp2->word);
                strcpy(tmp2->word, wrd);

            }
            tmp1=tmp1->next;
            tmp2 = tmp2->next;
        }
        tmp1 = head;
    }
}

void printfLinkedList(node *head)
{
    node *iter = head;
    while(iter!=NULL)
    {
         printf("%s ->", iter->word);
         iter=iter->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    node *list = NULL;
    list=addToLinkedList(list,"one" );
    list=addToLinkedList(list,"two" );
    list=addToLinkedList(list, "three");
    list=addToLinkedList(list,"four" );
    list=addToLinkedList(list,"five" );
    printfLinkedList(list);
    sortList(list);
    printfLinkedList(list);

    return 0;
}
```

Instead of counting the number of loop cycles, I suggest to check that `tmp1` and `tmp2`are both not `NULL`.

```
void sortList(node *head)
{
    int len = listLenght(head);

    int i,j;
   
    for(i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        node *tmp1 = head;
        node *tmp2 = (tmp1 != NULL) ? tmp1->next : NULL;
        while((tmp1 != NULL) && (tmp2 != NULL))
        {
            int idx = 0;
            while(tmp1->word[idx] == tmp2->word[idx])
                idx++;

            if(tmp1->word[idx] > tmp2->word[idx])
            {
                char wrd[100];
                strcpy(wrd, tmp1->word);
                strcpy(tmp1->word, tmp2->word);
                strcpy(tmp2->word, wrd);

            }
            tmp1=tmp1->next;
            tmp2 = tmp2->next;
        }
        tmp1 = head;
    }
}
```

The check for equal characters may access data after the end of the array if all characters are equal. This is undefined behavior and may result in a segmentation fault as well.

Make sure you stop reading at the end of the string.

```
            while((tmp1->word[idx] == tmp2->word[idx]) &&
                  (tmp1->word[idx] != '\0'))
                idx++;
```

Instead of implementing the string comparison yourself you could also use `strcmp`.

```
void sortList(node *head)
{
    int len = listLenght(head);

    int i,j;
   
    for(i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        node *tmp1 = head;
        node *tmp2 = (tmp1 != NULL) ? tmp1->next : NULL;
        while((tmp1 != NULL) && (tmp2 != NULL))
        {
            int idx = 0;
            if(strcmp(tmp1->word, tmp2->word) > 0)
            {
                char wrd[100];
                strcpy(wrd, tmp1->word);
                strcpy(tmp1->word, tmp2->word);
                strcpy(tmp2->word, wrd);

            }
            tmp1=tmp1->next;
            tmp2 = tmp2->next;
        }
        tmp1 = head;
    }
}
```